# ArrayList Contains with Object always returns false

Tags: java, object, arraylist, contains

Here is my code:

```
package bikeproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class BikerList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();

        int mountainBikeSales = 0;
        int roadBikeSales = 0;

        fillArray(bikes);

        displayStock(bikes);

//      calculateStock(bikes);
        System.out.println(displayBkeNumbers(bikes));
    }

    static void fillArray(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        Random rand = new Random();
//      int number = 2;
//      int a = rand.nextInt(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (rand.nextInt(2) < 1) {
//              System.out.println(rand.nextInt(2));
                bikes.add(new MountainBike());
            } else {
//              System.out.println(rand.nextInt(2));
                bikes.add(new RoadBike());
            }
        }
    }

    static void displayStock(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        for (Bike bike : bikes) {
            System.out.println(bike);
        }
    }

    static int calculateStock(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        int bikesSold = 0;
        for (Bike bike : bikes) {
            if (bikes.contains(new MountainBike())) {
                bikesSold++;
            }
        }
        return bikesSold;
    }

    static String displayBkeNumbers(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        int mb = 0;
        int rb = 0;

        mb = calculateStock(bikes);
        rb = bikes.size() - mb;

        return "\nStock Levels" + "\nWe have " + mb + " mountain Bike in Stock" + "\nWe have " + rb
                + " Road bikes in Stock";
    }
}
```

I really believe there is an error in the `calculateStock()` method because it always returns false, In the `calculateStock()` method I want to add the value to the `bikesSold` variable if each bike in the array is an instance of a mountain bike.

The output generated by the code above:

```
Stock Levels
We have 0 mountain Bike in Stock
We have 10 Road bikes in Stock
```

Mountain Bike is always 0 although it is already in the `ArrayList`.

The expected output, something like this:

```
Stock Levels
We have 4 Mountain Bikes in stock
We have 6 Road Bikes in stock
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code for `Bike`.  Probably you didn't implement `equals()` properly.

Comment: You're checking if the list contains a mountain bike that you just created - which is definitely not in the list. You should use `if(bike instanceof MountainBike) { ... }` rather than contains. Although, this is not a good way of doing this.

Comment: The problem is that calculateStock () always returns false, which I'm sure it shouldn't be @ Giorgi Tsiklauri

Comment: Please show your Bike code. This has already been requested of you.

Comment: Has been edited. Thanks @GiorgiTsiklauri

Comment: No, I'm still confused

Comment: `.contains(...)` should not be used, have to wait for this question to be re-opened before posting my answer though.

Comment: Okay thanks everyone who tried to help, I'll try again later.

Comment: `.contains()` answers if a thing is in the list, it does not answer how many of that thing are in the list.

Comment: I tried to answer but before pasting my code your question status is closed, I don't know why you add all your classes here I tried to update your question it waiting for approval then I'll past my answer but if it's urgent ping me on linkedIn, complete name Azhar Mobeen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
static int calculateStock(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
    int bikesSold = 0;
    for (Bike bike : bikes) {
        if (bikes.contains(new MountainBike())) { //problematic line
            bikesSold++;
        }
    }
    return bikesSold;
}
```

does not work, because, [`.contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

> returns true if and only if this list contains **at least one element** e such that Objects.equals(o, e).

So, `bikes.contains(new MountainBike())` will always return `true` as long as there is, at least, one instance of the `MountainBike` *contained* (according to the `.equals(Object o)` method) in the `bikes` list.

Rather, you should want to check if the *current* object is an instance of a particular type you would want to check it against (`MountainBike`, in this case), like this:

```java
static int calculateStock(ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
    int bikesSold = 0;
    for (Bike bike : bikes) {
        if (bike instanceof MountainBike) {
            bikesSold++;
        }
    }
    return bikesSold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `if (bikes.contains(new MountainBike()))`  creates a new object and checks if it's already in the list. It's not.

You need to do something like `if (bike instanceof Mountainbike)` .

There are better ways, but that will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm curious why this got a downvote? Other than `Mountainbike` should be `MountainBike`.

Comment: This completely ignores that if Bike implements the equals method in a certain way, the `contains` method will in fact work. My guess is that this is the point of this exercise.

Comment: I'd argue that `Bike` could override `contains` and not even call `equals`, in which case this approach would make more sense with how the code reads

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter what implementation of equals will make it work except `return this.class == other.class`?

Comment: Basically OP asked a question lacking enough information to answer it with regards to `Bike#equals` and therefor this answer solves the *problem*.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter the `contains` method will work. but `calculateStock` will not. `calculateStock` will work if this answer is used.